# Is there a recommended order for reading Flash Gordon?

Tags: comics, suggested-order, flash-gordon

I'm having some trouble to decide where to start to read the Flash Gordon comic strips. Initially I'm interested to know how Flash Gordon helped the people of Mongo, but I don't know which issues contains that arc and neither what to read later. Where should I start to?